# ReResources$NotFoundException when initialising my adapter

Tags: android, exception, resources, adapter

After i get a list of messages from my presenter i call this method to initialize my adapter:

```
@Override
public void displayChatMessages(ArrayList<Message> messageList) {
    mMessageList.clear();
    mMessageList.addAll(messageList);
    ChatMessageAdapter mAdapter = new ChatMessageAdapter(this, mMessageList, requestId);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

When the onCreateViewHolder method is called within the adapter:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public ChatViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_message_item_layout, parent, false);

    return new ChatViewHolder(v);
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: uk.co.transreport.pa.dev, PID: 15725
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0b0033
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2418)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:4062)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:2234)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:882)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
    at uk.co.transreport.pa.Adapters.ChatMessageAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ChatMessageAdapter.java:134)
    at uk.co.transreport.pa.Adapters.ChatMessageAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ChatMessageAdapter.java:51)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6685)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5869)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:589)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3529)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4082)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16922)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1077)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16922)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
    at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:606)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16922)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16922)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16922)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16922)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16922)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16922)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2413)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2122)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1264)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6944)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Ch
```

I've checked a bunch of similar questions but I was only able to find a bunch of answers regarding wrong data types when it comes to displaying the information in TextViews....I know this is not the case for me because i commented all the code within my onBindViewHolder method.

I cleaned and rebuild the project...thought it was something bad with cached layout references but didn't helped.

Does anybody have a clue why I keep getting this?

Comment: what is `requestId`?

Comment: its a specific integer that i use in another feature , redundant in this situation

Comment: Share your whole adapter with question

Comment: I commented most of the code in the Adapter...I just tried using another layout resource inside onCreateViewHolder and it worked...I don't get it why it doesn't like me current layout resource

Comment: found the issue. Inside my layout I was including another layout that was existing only in my layout-v23 folder.

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Comment: happy to hear that your problem is solved